# Bootstrap dropdown menu disappears when the input text is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to include an input text in a bootstrap dropdown menu.  But when I click the input text the menu disappears. This is the html code:

```
    <th width="25px;">
        <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                N°
                <span class="caret"></span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                <label for="usr">Find:</label>
                <li><input type="text" class="form-control"/></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="action">Asc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="another action">desc</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </th>
```

I put the followng javascript, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.dropdown-menu input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: First thing I would like to say is that you are mixing up css and html. For example, in HTML you define width as follows: `width="20"`.

Comment: It works for me in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94pkcnqy/

Comment: its working fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/re8ugjyt/1/

Comment: its weird, maybe my ,twig page is not loading the jquery plugin properly. I'm using: {% block javascripts %} 
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}

Comment: if that is the case it should rise `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery`

Comment: It doesn't rise that, btw the console is not showing errors.